# how to get Touch Event Pressure?

Tags: android

I need to get the pressure of touch event. I used event.getPressure() method to get the pressure and i found that pressure is always gives the value as 0.

I worked on Simulator but haven't tested on device. Is there a way where we can get the pressure of touch event in Simulator?

Please help me.

Comment: how to get small variations in pressure?i mean that,if we touch on the screen,then small pressure variation occurs while press long time.then how to get small variations?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the emulator will always give 0 for that method, as there is no way to calculate the pressure of a mouse click.

Also, why do you require this? According to the Android Reference, this value can vary a lot depending on the device and it's calibration. It doesn't seem like a great thing to use.